# How to catch this range of IP addresses with a netmask?

Tags: redirection, openwrt, netmask

I have an OpenWRT router and a Pi-hole install within the network.

I am aware that some devices may ignore the DNS provided by DHCP and use hardcoded ones, so I want to redirect DNS from all non-critical devices in the network to pi-hole. I know I can use [firewall rules](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/redirect-all-outbound-dns-traffic-to-internal-ip/18783/2).

However, the devices whose DNS requests I want to intercepts are in the IP range 16-239, which cannot be caught with a simple /xx netmask.

How can I catch with fw3 rules the IPs 16-239 in the most compact way?

I can only think about 16 separate firewall entries x.x.x.x/28 starting from x.x.x.16/28 up to x.x.x.224/28.

Answer (score 0):

This range requires at least 6 separate netmasks:

```
x.x.x.16/28
x.x.x.32/27
x.x.x.64/26
x.x.x.128/26
x.x.x.192/27
x.x.x.224/28
```

Tools used to calculate this list:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ipaddress
a = ipaddress.ip_address("x.x.x.16")
b = ipaddress.ip_address("x.x.x.239")
for n in ipaddress.summarize_address_range(a, b):
    print(n)
```

However, if you're able to bypass the OpenWRT configuration format, you can do this in just 3 rules by *excluding* the "critical" addresses before they reach a LAN-wide /24 rule:

```
-s x.x.x.0/28   -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-s x.x.x.240/28 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-s x.x.x.0/24   -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to...
```

Or if you're able to directly specify iptables modules, you could use the 'iprange' module:

```
-m iprange --src-range x.x.x.16-x.x.x.239 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT ...
```